# Listing Notebook instances tags can takes ages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently using the boto3 SDK from a Lambda function in order to retrieve various information about the Sagemaker Notebook Instances deployed in my account (almost 70 so not that many...)

One of the operations I am trying to perform is **listing the tags for each instance.**

However, from time to time **it takes ages to return the tags** : my Lambda either gets stopped (I could increase the timeout but still...) or a *ThrottlingException* is raised from the *sagemaker.list_tags* function (which could be avoided by increasing the number of retry upon sagemaker boto3 client creation) :

```
sagemaker = boto3.client("sagemaker", config=Config(retries = dict(max_attempts = 10)))
instances_dict = sagemaker.list_notebook_instances()

if not instances_dict['NotebookInstances']:
    return "No Notebook Instances"

while instances_dict:
    for instance in instances_dict['NotebookInstances']:
        print instance['NotebookInstanceArn']
        start = time.time()
        tags_notebook_instance = sagemaker.list_tags(ResourceArn=instance['NotebookInstanceArn'])['Tags']
        print (time.time() - start)
    instances_dict = sagemaker.list_notebook_instances(NextToken=instances_dict['NextToken']) if 'NextToken' in instances_dict else None
```

If you guys have any idea to avoid such delays :)

TY

Comment: What do you consider "ages"? 10 seconds? 5 minutes?

Comment: Hello @jarmod, by "ages" I mean 10 sec, sometimes 20 ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted you're getting throttled.  Rather than increasing the number of retries you might try to change the delay (i.e. increase the growth_factor).  Seems to be configurable looking at https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/data/_retry.json#L83

Note that buckets (and refill rates) are usually at the second granularity.  So with 70 ARNs you're looking at some number of seconds; double digits does not surprise me.

You might want to consider breaking up the work differently since adding retries/larger growth_factor will just increase the length of time the function will run.

I've had pretty good success at breaking things up so that the Lambda function only processes a single ARN per invocation.  The Lambda is processing work (I'll typically use a SQS queue to manage what needs to be processed) and the rate of work is configurable via a combination of configuring the Lambda and the SQS message visibility.

Not know what you're trying to accomplish outside of your original Lambda I realize that breaking up the work this way might (or will) add challenges to what you're doing overall.

It's also worth noting that if you have CloudTrail enabled the tags will be part of the event data (request data) for the "EventName" (which matches the method called, i.e. CreateTrainingJob, AddTags, etc.).

A third option would be if you are trying to find all of the notebook instances with a specific tag then you can use Resource Groups to create a query and find the ARNs with those tags fairly quickly.

- CloudTrail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
- Resource Groups: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
- Lambda with SQS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ken-Amazon, I'll take a look at your various proposals